# "[(ngModel)]" weird issue after a subscribe using apollo, not updating

Tags: angular, apollo

I'm having a weird problem with [(ngModel)]. I'm starting to use Angular 5 and I already created a form with inputs and it works. To connect to the database I'm using Apollo to send GraphQL queries and mutations. Basically I'm doing a simple settings page that can create, delete and edit settings. Creating and Deleting settings works like a charm, is in the edit settings form I'm having trouble. I did exactly the same thing as in the create form and then in the ngOnInit() I'm making an query and adding it to the variable that holds all the inputs contents. When I load up the form I can see the values in the form, but when I edit them the ngModel is not updating.

I have an Interface called Setting

```
export interface Setting {
    id?: number;
    ...
    active: boolean;
    name: string;
}
```

And this is part of my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-settings-edit',
    templateUrl: './settings-edit.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./settings-edit.component.css']
})
export class SettingsEditComponent implements OnInit {

    conf: Setting = {
        ...
        active: false,
        name: null
    };

    constructor(private apollo: Apollo,
                private router: Router,
                private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.getConf(id);
    }

    getConf(id){
        this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
            query: GET_CONF,
            variables:{
                id: id
            }
        }).valueChanges.subscribe(({data})=>{

            this.conf = data.getConfiguration;

        })
    }

    updateConf(form: NgForm) {
        if(form.valid){
            this.apollo.mutate({
                mutation: UPDATE_CONF,
                refetchQueries: [{
                    query: ALL_SETTINGS_QUERY
                }],
                variables: {
                    id: this.conf.id,
                    ...
                    active: this.conf.active,
                    name: this.conf.name
                }
            }).subscribe(({data}) => {
                this.router.navigate(["/settings"]);
            })
        }

    }

    ...

}
```

This is part of my html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error has-feedback': hasErrors(name)}">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Configuration Name" [(ngModel)]="conf.name"
        #name="ngModel" required>
      <span *ngIf="hasErrors(name)" class="fa fa-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Activate?:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="conf.active" name="active"></mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a GIF of the problem I'm facing:

[image: gif1]

Now I did noticed something, which I find weird:

If I change this code to this (Ugly I know) it works:

```
this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
  query: GET_CONF,
  variables:{
      id: id
  }
}).valueChanges.subscribe(({data})=>{
  // If I change this line from:
  // this.conf = data.getConfiguration;
  // to
  this.conf = <Setting>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.getConfiguration));
})
```

I replaced it to `this.conf = <Setting>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.getConfiguration));`

What I get from Apollo I JSON stringify and parse it again. it Works..

Here:

[image: gif2]

Any reason why this could be happening? Is it typescript related? or is it Angular? Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you show your table what you binding?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code? It may works. I also had the same problem.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control border-input" 
placeholder="Configuration Name" [ngModel]="conf.name" 
(onModelChange)="changeConfigurationName($event)" #name="ngModel" required>

changeConfigurationName(event) {
    this.conf.name = event;
}
```

Comment: Hi @pratik-gadoya, Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this in my form and it didn't work.. The event wasn't firing. I put a console.log inside and nothing was sent to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Recently happened upon this issue myself when trying to edit a response from Apollo using `ngModel`. This issue is actually due to the fact that Apollo freezes the response objects ([link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/issues/329)), thus you have to copy the object in order to edit it. That's why converting the JSON to a string and back again works. Alternatively you can use the spread operator to copy it (or `Object.assign`).

```
this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
  query: GET_CONF,
  variables:{
      id: id
  }
}).valueChanges.subscribe(({ data }) => {
  this.conf = {...data.getConfiguration};
})
```

Note that, `Object.assign` and the spread operator only create shallow copies. If you have an object with nested objects then you'll to use something like lodash to perform a deep copy.